# Conway's and Kochen's SPIN axiom seems unphysical

Tags: quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations, foundations, epr-experiment

In their "Free will theorem", Conway's and Kochen's states the "SPIN axiom":
"A triple experiment for the frame (x, y, z) always yields
the outcomes 1, 0, 1 in some order."

I understand that they mean +/- 1. I also understand the idea that the eigenvalues of the squared spin matrices in the three directions are 0 and 1, and that their sum is 2. But still, their statement is false when speaking about actual measurement:

Say we take a spin-1 particle and measure its spin on the x-direction, and get +1 (thus the state of the spin is now (1/2)*(1,\sqrt(2),1) in the basis of the spin-z eigenvector, but that's not so important).
Next, we measure the spin on the z-direction. This has some probability (1/4, actually) to be +1, and suppose that's what happens. So now the state is (1,0,0).
Finally, we measure the spin on the y-direction. Again, there is a non-zero probability (of 1/4) to get +1 - this can be verified by going through the spin matrices, but actually this is not really necessary, as the situation is identical up to rotation to the previous one.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: I just realized it is the squared spin that is measured, and the squared spins in all 3 axes commute for a spin-1 particle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kochen-Specker theorem (which the Free Will Theorem uses as a lemma) does not involve measurements of $J_x,J_y,J_z$. Instead, it involves measurements of $J_x^2,J_y^2,J_z^2$.

Measuring $J_z^2$ is not the same as measuring $J_z$ and then squaring the resulting eigenvalue. If the initial state is $(a,b,c)$, then the possible states after a $J_z^2$-measurement are $(a,0,c)$ and $(0,b,0)$. Similarly for $J_x^2$ and $J_y^2$. For a spin $1$ particle, each of these measurements has only two eigenspaces, not three. This should resolve the paradox.